# Dockerizing react app with webpack, connection issues

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, webpack

I'm lately trying to dockerize my react app to learn docker.
I'm using weback for managing this project.
Now here is the thing, after I run dev script `npm run dev`, server gets on, but I'm not able to connect to it either on host (posting container on `3000:3000`) and inside container for any-given ports that came up to my mind (like 8000, 8080, 3000, 5000). It just seems to me like the port connection is not set up properly.
Reading some webpack docs did not give me any clue.

The questions are: best way to define server scripts to run ?
My way of doing it is:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
```

Is there any default-like port that webpack sets its connection to (maybe a way to change it)?

What I did establish, is that for 90% it's my webpack config. After dockerizing react app with create-react-app I did have successfull start.

My webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: { index: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.js") }, //"./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: When running your docker container run `docker port test` in the terminal.  Does it show that the port is listed?

Comment: @objectObject Yes. Listing all the containers shows that there is 0.0.0.0:3000:3000 (the way I set it)

Comment: Awesome.  And inside of the docker container are you able to confirm that there is an instance of node running?  `ps aux | grep node`

Comment: @objectObject after I `npm run dev' inside container, only message of ps i get is :
`79 pts/1    00:00:00 ps`

Comment: interesting what flavor of docker container are you using?

Comment: Also, I am remembering that I personally wrapped my docker containers with a NGINX reverse proxy so that I could use domains.  If outside of the container you run https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/ check the response to see if any of the IP Addresses listed there work.

Comment: @objectObject I will use nginx reverse proxy, but first i wanted to split my django rest and react. If what I'm using `node:14` which, I think is something of debian.
With this setup i should be able to get webpack-deb-server on some port.

Comment: NGINX reverse proxy setups can be a little intense.  Check the inspection first and see whether any of those IP addresses listed lead you to the application first.  Running the node docker container should allow you to achieve your desired results w/o the additional fanfare